# How can I install the LiveDVD in inside Windows (VMWare)?

Tags: windows, wubi, vmware, livedvd

I have downloaded the Ubuntu 11.10 (64bit) LiveDVD. I have also installed it on my system (with a partition) successfully.
Now I need to experiment with Linux so I want to install Ubuntu in inside Windows or VMware. VMware shows errors for 64bit (no 64bit cpu), and `wubi.exe open the window with no installation button.

There is no option for installation, only have Demo and Information. I tried this in two different systems (both Windows 7 32bit), both gave the same result.

What is the problem?
Can the LiveDVD be installed inside Windows?

Comment: why don't you experiment with Ubuntu that you've already installed?

Comment: system maybe break or congested.

Comment: then you just re-install! that's the whole point of having Linux! make the changes, if they don't work, then re-install! :D

Comment: Download the 32-bit DVD instead, and it should work in vmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the 32bit DVD inside VMWare (as Sakjur) suggested. You can also try Virtualbox and enable 64bit CPU emulation (if your processor supports VT-x).